# How to effectively perform math functions like average on values of 2 separate dictionaries

Tags: python

```
dict1 = {'Sammy Student': '65', 'Betty Student1': '45', 'Alice Student2': '100', 'tom Student3': '50', 'Varun Student4': '90'}

dict2 = {'Sammy Student': '85', 'Betty Student1': '65', 'Alice Student2': '90', 'tom Student3': '60', 'Varun Student4': '100'}
```

Currently i'm doing it like:

```
dict3 = {'Sammy Student' , (int(dict1['Sammy Student']) + int(dict2['Sammy Student']))/2}
```

So wanted to know if there is a more optimized/effective way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you store the number strings as ints?

Comment: Check out [the statistics module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like that instead:

```
dict3 = {k: (int(v) + int(dict2.get(k, '0')))/2 for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

this is a dictionary-comprehension that loops through the `key`-`value` pairs of `dict1` and for every one of those `key`s fetches the corresponding `value` from `dict2` too. It converts both to `int`egers and derives their average.

Note the `.get(..)` method used instead of the `dict2[k]` that makes sure no error is raised if a `key` is missing from `dict2` but present in `dict1`.

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you :)  Thanks again for the explanation (y)